# Can not find moved-to-system app after update

Tags: applications, root-access, internal-storage

I moved some apps (*WhatsApp* and *Amaze*) to `/system/app` using the [*/system/app/mover*](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.j4velin.systemappmover) some time ago. Now my phone did an update (I have a Meizu MX5 with Flyme OS) and I can't seem to find the apps anywhere, neither in the *F-Droid Apps* section for *Amaze*, in the */system/app/mover* application, in the `/system/app` folder or in *Settings/Apps*.

When I try to install the apps from the application market, it says that the apps are already installed and I see the same version number like this:

[image: WhatsApp replaced]

When I press continue nothing seems to happen and I still cannot find the app anywhere. How can I retrieve these apps?

Comment: This is a typical problem with systemless root- reported here also. Only way to is remove systemless , root normal and convert- my understanding

Comment: I don't think it's systemless, I checked `/system/xbin` and there is a `su` shell file.